# User-defined function not getting implemented as per required. Logic somehow getting failed

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

This is my user-defined function in which I've passed array. Function returns true upon whether string element within array has size greater than 3 and false when condition not satisfied:

```
    function criteria_fn(){
    G = arguments[0]
    for(i in G){
        if(G[i].length > 3){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This is the array:

```
Array = ['A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'AA', 'AAAAA', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AAAA']
```

I am trying to call the function two times in different ways:

```
Case 1 : V1 = Array.filter(function(i){return !criteria_fn(i)})    # For 
returning array which doesn't satisfies function's criteria

Case 2 : V2 = Array.filter(function(i){return criteria_fn(i)})     # For 
returning array which satisfies the function's criteria
```

When filter function returns elements that don't fulfill the criteria_fn's condition in Case 1 returns all the elements.

```
O/P : [
      'A',     'AA',
      'AAA',   'AA',
      'AAAAA', 'A',
      'A',     'A',
      'AAAA'
       ]
```

However I am having the array with condition satisfied from Case 2 as such :

```
O/P :  [
        'A',   'AA',    
        'AAA', 'AA',    
        'A',   'A',     
        'A'
       ]
```

My question is 1. Why all the elements are outputted in Case 1? 2. In Case 2, elements with length 3 are also getting outputted even when condition is specified to skip elements with length 3. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should test your `criteria_fn` by itself before testing it on an array. I'm not that familiar with JavaScript, but this is what I get:

```js
criteria_fn('A')
false
criteria_fn('AA')
false
criteria_fn('AAA')
false
criteria_fn('AAAA')
false
criteria_fn('AAAAA')
false
criteria_fn('AAAAAA')
false
```

It seems pretty clear to me that your problem can be broken down into this one function and the other (how to apply `Array.filter` to all elements) can be dealt with separately.

A couple extra things:

- Don't overwrite the `Array` (capitalized) variable, you're overwriting a built-in-object. Use a lowercase variable, like `my_array`.
- Format your code, especially if you're asking other people to read it.